# Verify link integrity to local html files

Tags: java, html, testing, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink

Is there a way to test if a link is valid to a local html file on my hdd? I have a couple of *.htm files, in which I'm searching for all links in the document. I'm searching for all  link elements and for the link from the href attribute of the element. I tried to test for a valid link with silenium and HttpURLConnection, but the href targets I want to test, are in the form of `file:///C://root//example.htm`. This is not working for me, because it's a local file and I got a CastException:

`URL url = new URL("file:///C://root//example.htm");`

```
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(1500);

    httpURLConnect.connect();

    if(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode() == 200)
    {
        System.out.println(href + " - " + httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `java.io.File` class?

An example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath = "c:\\test1.txt";
    boolean fileExists = checkIfFileExists(filePath);

    System.out.println( String.format("The file in \"%s\" exists? %s", filePath, fileExists));
}

public static boolean checkIfFileExists(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    return file.isFile();
}
```

It will print something like:

> The file in "c:\test1.txt" exists? true

Comment: This is a good point and I also thought about this, but I also have sometimes anchors in the link and I also want to check the anchors in the target links, e.g. file:///C://root//example.htm#myanchor